# biblatex: adding URL to techreport title doesn't work

Tags: biblatex

Using `\DeclareFieldFormat` to add the URL to titles as a `href` doesn't work on a `@techreport` entry, though it works fine on, for instance, `@phdthesis`.  Why would that be, I wonder?

[image: Screenshot of the MNWE. Title of tech report is not a link.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, american]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,
   inbook,
   incollection,
   inproceedings,
   patent,
   thesis,
   unpublished,
   techreport, % some problem here?
   misc,
   phdthesis]
  {title}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@techreport{probation-report,
  title={{Problem solving and mathematical knowledge}},
  author={Joseph Corneli},
  institution={Knowledge Media Institute},
  url={http://kmi.open.ac.uk/publications/techreport/kmi-10-03},
  year={2010},
}

@phdthesis{corneli-thesis,
    title = {Peer produced peer learning: {A} mathematics case study},
    school = {The Open University (submitted)},
    author = {Corneli, Joseph},
    year = {2013},
        url={http://metameso.org/~joe/docs/submitted-version.pdf},
},
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}
My probation report --- \fullcite{probation-report} --- doesn't
actually resemble my thesis that closely ---
\fullcite{corneli-thesis}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`techreport` is an alias for `report`; you don't get the URL in the `phdthesis` if you comment out the type `thesis`, for instance.

So, add `report` to the types:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,
   inbook,
   incollection,
   inproceedings,
   patent,
   thesis, % also phdthesis
   unpublished,
   report, % also techreport
   misc,
  ]{title}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}
```